# How to table.insert(x) from table.remove(x)

Tags: lua

I want to manipulate a lua table by adding and removing elements. 
I would use table.remove(x), store (x) into an array and then insert it back with table.insert(x).

```
a = {}
table.remove(tab, a) -- From tab into a
...
table.insert(tab, a) -- From a into tab
```

That won't work.

Comment: What position do you want to insert/remove elements?

Comment: I’d like to remove the elements starting from the head of table and insert them back in the same order (eg. the head remains the head)

Answer (score 2):

Simply because that is not how they work.

Please refer to [`table.insert`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.insert) and [`table.remove`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-table.remove) of Lua Reference Manual. This one is for Lua 5.1, if you use different version then you should be able to easily find proper one.

You can move elements between tables like this:

```
a = {}
table.insert(a, table.remove(tab)) -- From tab into a
...
table.insert(tab, table.remove(a)) -- From a into tab
```

You may need to verify value returned by `remove`:

```
local foo = table.remove(tab)
if type(foo) ~= "nil" then
    table.insert(a, foo)
end
```

Note that default position for `remove` is the last element of the table and default position for `insert` is after last element of the table. Manipulating `pos` argument of either `insert` or `remove` may allow you to implement different behaviours.

For instance if you would like to get more scrolling-like behaviour (the one you asked for in your previous, now deleted, question):

```
a = {}
local foo = table.remove(tab, 1)
if type(foo) ~= "nil" then table.insert(a, foo) end -- From tab into a
...
local bar = table.remove(a, 1)
if type(bar) ~= "nil" then table.insert(tab, bar) end -- From a into tab
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed, I'll try that in a few hours and let you know. Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Comment: Why are you quoting nil?

Comment: @glennjackman `type` returns string. I'm not checking if value is `nil` but check its type.